Error when sending email to mail.com from c# console
I'm trying to send an email from a .NET console app via Mail.com SMTP. I've triple checked the values, but I keep getting an error:

SMTP Error: MustIssueStartTlsFirst - The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

Here is how I set it:
// Create an SMTP client
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailUser, EmailPassword),
    EnableSsl = true, // Ensure SSL/TLS is enabled
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false
};

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell there is no 2-factor authentication required when using Mail.com

I'm pretty sure you need to set UseDefaultCredentials = false before you call         Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailUser, EmailPassword). Since UseDefaultCredentials resets your Credentials to null.

you are using ssl but your mail server is requiring tls , please change that and retry

What Port number are you using?  You cannot use port 25 with SSL/TLS.  Check you mail server webpage to find out required smtp settings.  Are you sending more than one email?  You need a new smtp client for each email.

EnableSsl = true // Enable SSL for TLS and Port = 587, // Port for TLS.  If you know another way, please place code in comments.

I changed the code "        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort)
{
UseDefaultCredentials = false,
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailUser, EmailPassword),
EnableSsl = true, // Ensure SSL/TLS is enabled
DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    };" although the documentation says it doesn't matter.  It made no difference


I'm using port 587 which I also use to connect to outlook and gmail in the code without issues.
